# Save Dialog only appear once?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, save, pyqt4

I am currently making a desktop widget and what I want to do is create a file in which a user can edit and then save. However, if you guys are familiar with Microsoft word or any other text editors, I want it so that after you hit File -> save, a save dialog appears in which you can choose where to save the file and the file's name. However, after the first time, if the file name stays the same, the save dialog will not come up--rather it will just automatically save over what was previously written. This is what I want to implement but I am having trouble trying to do this. Following is my method for saving files using the save dialog but I am unsure on how to save without having the save dialog pop up.

```
def saveFile(self):
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, 'Save File', os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Calendar Data/"+self.dateString), ".txt") 
    f = open(filename, 'w') 
    filedata = self.text.toPlainText()
    f.write(filedata)
    f.close()
```

Anyone have any idea how to do this? If so that would be great! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make `filename` an instance attribute, so you can just check if it was already set:

```
class Spam:
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = None

    def saveFile(self):
        if not self.filename:
            self.filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(...)
            # here you should check if the dialog wasn't cancelled
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.text.toPlainText())
    ...
```